# Cannot enable code quality and code climate in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, code-climate

I have a CI/CD pipeline setup for my gitlab project. It runs multiple stages.
I want to setup a code quality analysis, from what I understood of the gitlab documentation, the config should be very straightforward : [Gitlab - Code Quality](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html).

So what I did, first, I added a .codeclimate.yml file in root project directory :

```
version: "2"         # required to adjust maintainability checks
plugins:
  gnu-complexity:
    enabled: true
```

Then I added the required include and stage in my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - test
...
include:
      - template: Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml
...
```

However, upon running the pipeline again, I still have no code quality tab and both the gitlab template and the code climate plugin don't seem to be executed at all.

What's strange is that I setup the gitlab SAST using the procedure and it worked well out of the box.

Did I do something wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you mean it's not executing at all? Is there a code quality job? Or does the job never trigger? If there is a job, what's the output? Are you accidentally overwriting the job in your CI YAML file? Which workflow are you using? Are you using a private runner?